# Twitter Player Card not auto-expanding on Mobile

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-card

[I read that Twitter recently set their Player Cards to auto-expand in their native iOS and Android applications.](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/player#The_Player_Card_across_platforms)

My site is Twitter approved, but when I view the card through the mobile application, it is not auto-expanded:

[image]

I was surprised to see that there is at least a preview on Web:

[image]

Can anyone give me a hint as to what's going wrong?

These are my tags:

```
 <meta name="twitter:card" content="player">
 <meta name="twitter:site" content="@scientiffic">
 <meta name="twitter:title" content="scientiffic's Spin">
 <meta name="twitter:player" content="https://spin360-staging.herokuapp.com/videos/949.html">
 <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://spin360-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/image/image_file/1665/img000.jpg">
 <meta name="twitter:player:width" content="700">
 <meta name="twitter:player:height" content="700">
 <meta name="twitter:player:stream" content="https://spin360-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/video/video_file/949/spin_1665.mp4">
 <meta name="twitter:player:stream:content_type" content="video/mp4">
```

Comment: Hi i am facing the same problem. Do you find any solution?

Comment: @user2423768 I don't think there is an workaround for this, unfortunately.

Comment: hmm, do you have any idea how sound cloud and apple music player handle it because their playcard get expand in app too. so there must be some way.

Comment: @user2423768 I think they have special privileges because they are huge companies.